# How to resolve 'Unable to find file' when updating a property in a Lottie Animation View?

Tags: android, react-native, lottie

I have an issue with android. The file in the Android assets directory is not found.

Error:

> Error while updating property 'sourceName' of a view managed by: LottieAnimationView
>
> null
>
> Unable to find file loading.js

Animation file location:

```
app/src/main/assets/loading.json
```

Component:

```
class Loading extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={StyleSheet.loading.page}>
        <View style={StyleSheet.loading.animationWrapper}>
          <Animation
            ref={animation => { this.animation = animation }}
            style={StyleSheet.loading.animation}
            loop
            source="loading.json"
          />
        </View>
        <Text style={StyleSheet.loading.text}>LOADING</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Versions:

```
"lottie-react-native": "2.2.0"
"react-native": "0.47.2"
```

Comment: Apparently closing / reopening the project in Android Studio was enough to get it to work correctly.

Comment: No luck with trying this :(

Answer (score 0):

you should add your loading.json file in your javascript source code and require it

```
<Animation
   ref={animation => { this.animation = animation }}
   style={StyleSheet.loading.animation}
   loop
   source={require('./loading.json')}
/>
```